# Arranging Table Horizontally

Tags: php, css

I have a table in my main website, I want to make it so that when there are three columns, it automatically rearrange the arrangement of the tables after three be arranged to the right. The table on my site basically shows a picture of a laptop and the specs next to it (also in table form). Please help me with the coding as I cant seem to find a solution.

Language: CSS, PHP
Below is the attached picture of my site[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LId6U.png)

I tried to add borders to my table but it doesn't work for me

This is my code on php

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($laksana_pilihan)==0){
   # papar Tiada barangan yang telah direkodkan
   echo "Tiada barangan yang telah direkodkan";
}
else{
       
   # jika terdapat barangan yang ditemui
   # papar dalam bentuk jadual.
   echo "<table border=’1’>";
      
   # Pembolehubah $n mengambil data yang ditemui
   while($n=mysqli_fetch_array($laksana_pilihan)){
  
     # memaparkan semula data diambil oleh pembolehubah $n
     echo "  <tr> 
                 <td><img width='50%' src='img/".$n['gambar']."'></td>
                 <td>
                     <h3> <b> ".$n['jenama_barang']."</h3> </b><br>
                     
                     <h6>".$n['nama_barang']." <br>
                         ".$n['cpu']."<br>
                         ".$n['gpu']."<br>
                         RM".$n['harga']."</td>
                     </h6></tr>"; 
   }
   
   echo"</table>";
}
```

this is my code on css

```
body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1920px;
  height: 1080px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:100%;
  background-image: url('https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/962410626284683336/1107323813110222958/L_Daniel-02.png');
  margin:0;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: dotted;
  background-blend-mode: normal;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
font-size: xx-large;

}
/*td and tr is for the table*/
table{
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left:10%;
  top:19%;
  width: 25%;
  
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is a PHP problem? Can you share the **generated** markup and your attempts to resolve the problem?

Comment: You have closed the <td> tag before the <h6> tag

Comment: “I want to make it so that when there are three columns, it automatically rearrange the arrangement of the tables after three be arranged to the right” - I am having a really hard time parsing that

Comment: I, too, am struggling to understand what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to display three products per _row_? Whatever you want to achieve, it is unlikely that `<table>` is going to be appropriate markup. A quick search will reveal many thousands of articles and tutorials on product grid layouts.

Comment: Apologies for the misunderstanding, yes I do want to display 3 products per row, how can I do so?

Comment: If you want three columns per row, then after every third item you insert a row end and possibly a start. Or look into `array_chunk`

Answer (score 0):

**THIS SHOULD PROBABLY WORK, IT CREATES A SEPERATE TABLE FOR EVERY 3 ROWS. THEN YOU CAN USE CSS TO HORIZINTALLY ARRANGE THE TABLES**

```
 //initialize a variable $a which would increase with every row
    $a = 0;

    while($n=mysqli_fetch_array($laksana_pilihan)){
    //run the loop through each row
           
    
    if(($a / 3) <= 1){
    if the current row is 3 or less than 3, print a row
    
           # memaparkan semula data diambil oleh pembolehubah $n
      echo "  <tr> 
                      <td><img width='50%' src='img/".$n['gambar']."'></td>
                      <td>
                          <h3> <b> ".$n['jenama_barang']."</h3> </b><br>
                         
                          <h6>".$n['nama_barang']." <br>
                                  ".$n['cpu']."<br>
                                  ".$n['gpu']."<br>
                                   RM".$n['harga']."</td>
                                   </h6></tr>"; 
                       
                       
                        $a++;
    
    
    } else {
    // if the row is 4th or 5th or whatever greater than 3rd, close the table and create a new table
    
    
    if(($a % 3) == 1){
    //if it is 4th, 7th, or any new now row after 3 rows, close the table and create new one
    echo "</table> <table>";
    }
    
    
    echo "  <tr> 
                      <td><img width='50%' src='img/".$n['gambar']."'></td>
                      <td>
                          <h3> <b> ".$n['jenama_barang']."</h3> </b><br>
                         
                          <h6>".$n['nama_barang']." <br>
                                  ".$n['cpu']."<br>
                                  ".$n['gpu']."<br>
                                   RM".$n['harga']."</td>
                                   </h6></tr>"; 
   
    $a++;
    }
         }
      
          echo"</table>";
```

Comment: Please format your code properly, and add some explanation to it such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

My frontend dev skills are poor, at best, but hopefully this gets you heading in a better direction.

As this is a *list* of products, I would suggest `<ul>`, instead of `<table>`. And, we can use `<article>` for the product cards, as per MDN's reference for [`<article>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article):

> The `<article>` HTML element represents a self-contained composition in a document, page, application, or site, which is intended to be independently distributable or reusable (e.g., in syndication). Examples include: a forum post, a magazine or newspaper article, or a blog entry, **a product card**, a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget or gadget, or any other independent item of content.

Your PHP would become something like:

```php
if (mysqli_num_rows($laksana_pilihan) == 0) {

    # papar Tiada barangan yang telah direkodkan
    echo "Tiada barangan yang telah direkodkan";

} else {

    echo '<ul class="grid">';

    while ($n = mysqli_fetch_array($laksana_pilihan)) {
  
        echo <<<HTML

            <li>
                <article>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="img/{$n['gambar']}" alt=""/>
                    </figure>
                    <div>
                        <h3>{$n['jenama_barang']}</h3>
                        <p>{$n['nama_barang']}<br>
                           {$n['cpu']}<br>
                           {$n['gpu']}<br>
                           RM{$n['harga']}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </li>

HTML;

    }

    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Now we can define the `<ul>` as a grid container, and make the grid three columns of equal width with [grid-template-columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns):

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

Here's a little more CSS to get you started with the product cards:

```css
.grid {
    margin: 2rem;
    padding: 0;
    display: grid;
    gap: 1rem;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    list-style: none;
}

.grid li {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    height: 100%;
}

article {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 1rem;
}
```